# Script de busca não retorna resultados ou erros

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Bom, criei um script de busca em PHP, porém, ele não exibe resultados, e também não exibe erros.

Fomulário

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="pesquisa_card.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" name="search-text" maxlength="255">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><span class="sr-only">Buscar</span></button>
</form>
```

Pesquisa_Card.php

```
<?php
require("components/header.php");
require("php-scripts/conecta.php");
require("php-scripts/banco-cadastros.php");

$busca = $_POST["search-text"];

$buscados = pesquisaCards($conexao, $busca);
foreach ($buscados as $encontrado) {
  ?>
  <div>
    <!-- <?= $card['id'] ?> -->
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="<?= $encontrado['link_image'] ?>" alt="imagem de <?= $encontrado['card_name'] ?>">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><?= $encontrado['card_name'] ?></h3>
        <p><?= $encontrado['effect_description'] ?></p>
        <p class="btn-holder"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Detalhes</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Excluir</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}

require("components/footer.php");
```

Função de busca, puxada pelo banco-cadastros.php

```
function pesquisaCards($conexao, $busca){
    $buscados = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select C.id, C.card_name, C.monster_lrl, C.link_image, C.effect_description, C.card_atk, C.card_def, C.quantity, E.edition_name, E.edition_code, S.card_status_desc, A.kind_attribute, K.kind_name, M.kind_monster_name from card C inner join card_editions E on E.id = C.id_card_edition inner join kind_attributes A on A.id = C.id_kind_attributes inner join kind_card K on K.id = C.id_kind_card inner join kind_monster M on M.id = C.id_kind_monster inner join card_status S on S.id = C.id_card_status where (('card_name' like '%".$busca."%') or ('effect_description' like '%".$busca."%') or ('edition_name' '%".$busca."%') or ('edition_code' '%".$busca."%') or ('kind_attribute' '%".$busca."%') or ('kind_name' '%".$busca."%') or ('kind_monster_name' '%".$busca."%'))");
    while($encontrado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        array_push($buscados, $encontrado);
    };
    return $buscados;
};
```

Conexao

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cardsystem");
```

- Consegui Corrigir o primeiro erro, no qual não retornava nenhum valor, pois haviam espaços na query, entre as concatenações, que eram contados como parte da busca. Porém, ainda não retorna nenhum valor quando busco os registros, e, caso eu não escreva nada, ele retorna todos os valores do banco, não apresentando erros

Comment: provavelmente o erro esta na consulta verifica também se tens dados  correspondentes a essa consulta

Comment: eu verifiquei, tenho todos os dados, tanto que joguei no mysql e não foi apontado nenhum erro, mas também não retornou nenhum registro

Comment: tenta  adicionar registos e ve se funciona no php

Comment: É bom sempre antes de colocar o código SQL para rodar através da aplicação colocar para rodar no banco diretamente para verifica se retorna dados ou erros de sintaxe.

Comment: @ClaudioRamosdeOliveira, já realizei isso, porém ele não retorna erros, e também não retorna valores

Comment: @13dev como adiciono registros ?

Comment: @MuriloGambôa adicionar registros no mysql para ter insumos no php

Comment: existem registros, ao inserir a query no mysql, eu busco por "kaiju", sendo que possuo 8 registros de "kaiju" diferentes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para além do que disse o [Everaldo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227102/7210) você tem de colocar os prefixos das tabelas em cada campo:

```
$query = 

"SELECT C.id, C.card_name, C.monster_lrl, C.link_image, C.effect_description, 
C.card_atk, C.card_def, C.quantity, E.edition_name, E.edition_code, 
S.card_status_desc, A.kind_attribute, K.kind_name, M.kind_monster_name 
FROM card C 
INNER JOIN card_editions   E on E.id = C.id_card_edition 
INNER JOIN kind_attributes A on A.id = C.id_kind_attributes 
INNER JOIN kind_card       K on K.id = C.id_kind_card 
INNER JOIN kind_monster    M on M.id = C.id_kind_monster 
INNER JOIN card_status     S on S.id = C.id_card_status
WHERE ((C.card_name      like '%".$busca."%') 
OR (C.effect_description like '%".$busca."%') 
OR (E.edition_name       like '%".$busca."%') 
OR (E.edition_code       like '%".$busca."%') 
OR (A.kind_attribute     like '%".$busca."%') 
OR (K.kind_name          like '%".$busca."%') 
OR (M.kind_monster_name  like '%".$busca."%'))";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
```

Para além disso habitua-te a organizar o código que fica bem mais fácil de notar os erros como nesse que eu fiz.

Answer (score 6):

Reparei que no seu SQL tem um ERRO na condição utilizada, Está faltando escrever "LIKE" nas ultimas condições:

```
where 
(('card_name' like '%" . $busca . "%') or 
('effect_description' like '%" . $busca . "%') or 
('edition_name' '%" . $busca . "%') or  <-- Cade o LIKE
('edition_code' '%" . $busca . "%') or <-- Cade o LIKE
('kind_attribute' '%" . $busca . "%') or <-- Cade o LIKE
('kind_name' '%" . $busca . "%') or <-- Cade o LIKE
('kind_monster_name' '%" . $busca . "%'))<-- Cade o LIKE
```

Comment: adicionei os Like's e continua não rodando